# C custom random function

Tags: c, random, srand

I would like to create a fast lightweight function in C language that returns a pseudo random unsigned char. The challenging part for me (an ANSI C programmer)is that I cannot use the `<stdio.h>` or any other ready made functions. Any suggestions..?

by "fast" I meant: avoid unnecessary code (Eg if statements, loops etc)
by "lightweight" I meant: use as less variables as possible

thanks

Comment: Define "fast", "lightweight", and "random"...  Especially "random".

Comment: Is "the challenging part" synonymous for "the requirements of the homework assignment"?

Comment: int rand() { return 5;}

Comment: @GregS: Chosen by fair dice roll, I'm sure.

Comment: @Chris: Took 1024 bits from /dev/random, hashed it down to 512 bits with SHA512, then took the result mod 1 and added 5. Sounds random, right?

Comment: @GregS: you'd better patent that algorithm, sounds pretty premium to me.

Comment: Agree with Nemo, your requirements are a little too vague for a good answer. I have an answer that fulfills "fast" for sure, but I can't judge "lightweight" or "random" without knowing more about your application.

Comment: @Mannimarco First of all its not an university assignment. The university years are long gone. Its challenging for me because Im used in stdio.h and its hard to think outside of it.

Comment: @Nemo by fast I meant: avoid any useless loops. and lightweight: use as less variable as possible.

Comment: 11 minutes and no [xkcd link](http://xkcd.com/221/)? ??? What's becoming of SO?

Comment: @pmg, been there done that. And you've missed the companion [Dilbert](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/).

Comment: @Mark: I like Dilbert's best. Thanks :)

Comment: I reedited taking your notes in account. glad to see so many funny guys here.. the return 5; was a good one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Use a Linear Congruential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)

E.g.

```
uint32_t state = 777;

char myRand()
{
   state = state * 1664525 + 1013904223;
   return state >> 24;
}
```

Note that `myRand` returns the high bits, they are more pseudo-random than the low bits.

Linear Congruence Generators were introduced by D. H. Lehmer in 1949 (see Proc. 2nd Symp. on Large-Scale Digital Calculating Machinery (Cambridge, Mass.: Harvard University Press, 1951), 141-146). The concrete numeric constants I gave seem to originate from Press, William H.; et al. (1992). Numerical Recipes in Fortran 77: The Art of Scientific Computing (2nd ed.). ISBN 978-0-521-43064-7.

Comment: -1: LCGs are not all that random and should not be recommended for new applications.

Comment: I understood the OP that he wants a solution as simple as possible. No deterministic generator is random anyway.

Comment: If the OP's requirements rule out anything better than a LCRNG then they are in error.

Comment: Perhaps he wants to generate simple, low-grade 8-bit audio noise, who am I to know? An LCG as a reasonable choice for this.

Comment: It would be fair to say that this code is coutersy of Knuth, as seen in Numerical Recipes in C, second edition, page 284.

Comment: I checked my copy of Knuth, Seminumerical Algorithms. The code with the given constants, or even the constants alone are not there. Everything in the code besides the choice of constants is trivial, once the LCG scheme is given. I now added a note about its introduction by D.H. Lehmer in 1949 and about the presumed source of the constants I gave.

Answer (score 5):

From the linux kernel source code (random32.c)

the values in rnd_state should be initialized like: s1 > 1, s2 > 7, s3 > 15.

The paper claims this is a maximally equidistributed combined Tausworthe generator
based on code from GNU Scientific Library 1.5 (30 Jun 2004)

```
struct rnd_state {
    u32 s1, s2, s3;
};

static u32 __random32(struct rnd_state *state)
{
#define TAUSWORTHE(s,a,b,c,d) ((s&c)<<d) ^ (((s <<a) ^ s)>>b)

    state->s1 = TAUSWORTHE(state->s1, 13, 19, 4294967294UL, 12);
    state->s2 = TAUSWORTHE(state->s2, 2, 25, 4294967288UL, 4);
    state->s3 = TAUSWORTHE(state->s3, 3, 11, 4294967280UL, 17);

    return (state->s1 ^ state->s2 ^ state->s3);
}
```

Academia: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/tausme.ps

Comment: Maybe here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use

Answer (score 3):

Inventing your own random number generator is a bad idea of the same class as inventing your own cryptography: it is easy to construct something that *appears* to do the job but is in fact disastrously ineffective; constructing something that actually does do the job is much harder.  Read the cautionary tale of [RANDU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANDU), then download one of the variants of the [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html) and use that.

Comment: 2.5KB of internal state is lightweight in any modern environment but for the most deeply embedded, and the MT folks now also offer [TinyMT](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/TINYMT/index.html) which needs only 127 bits of internal state and is still better than any LCRNG.

Comment: This is one of the times where the OP wants something they shouldn't.  If an OP asked for advice with their implementation of RC4, would you give it to them?

Comment: how can you know he is not using a microcontroller?

Comment: He can still use TinyMT, or the Tausworthe generator you suggested, in that case.  Really, the only axes I'm trying to grind here are "nobody should use LCRNGs anymore" and "don't try to reinvent this wheel".

Comment: ok hexa got the point, and I thought I should reinvent a wheel that has been built a long time ago. I really don't know TINYMC but I will look it up. thx

Comment: but seriously, that RNG i suggested is pretty cool :D the linux kernel use it, why shouldn't you? :P

Comment: @Zack: Offtopic, but on the subject of RC4, check the cipher suite in use next time you connect to a large site with SSL...

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole list of pseudo-random number generators at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pseudorandom_number_generators